# sp_rename Object not found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-rename

I am doing a refactor of a database. In this process I am renaming some of the existing tables, keys and constraints. They will be recreated on the new refactored tables. Then data will be moved to the new tables before dropping the old tables.

I have one foreign key when I try to use `Exec sp_rename` I get an error back the object does not exist.
If I try to use `print object_id('xxx')` I get nothing back.

It is a valid object and I can find it in the `sys.objects table`.
If I try to use print `Object_Name('123456789')` with the object id from the `sys.objects` table it returns the name I am using in the `sp_rename`.

Any one got an idea why the `sp_rename` can not find the object?

Comment: what is the object name?

Comment: I don't understand why you are renaming a foreign key if you're going to recreate it?

Comment: Do you use `@objtype='OBJECT'`?

Comment: I am renaming keys because the tables structure is changing.  Moving fields from one to another and also adding new tables. First I have to rename the current Tables from Table1 to Table1_Old.  Then create the new tables.  Then I will move data from the old tables into the new tables. In some cases a few of the foreign keys on the new tables will be the same as the foreign keys on the old tables.  So the current foreign key like FK_Table1_Table2 will get renamed as FK_Table1_Table2_Old.  The new table structure will have a foreign key FK_Table1_Table2.

Comment: Here is what I try and results.

Comment: Select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix'  Returns 2066106401

Comment: Print object_Name('2066106401') Returns dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix

Comment: print object_id('dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix') Prints nothing

Comment: exec sp_rename 'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix', 'FK_FRPFileID_FRPDataMatrixImportETL'  Returns error object could not be found in current database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but I get this error "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.".  I believe the issue is some how when I created the foreign key the Schema name 'dbo.' is actually part of the name of the object.  So when I exec the sp_rename it looks in Schema dbo for FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix which doesn't exist.  The name really is dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix in the objects table.  If I manually remove the dbo. from the name under Keys then and rename it.  Need to fix this on my production database.

Comment: Are you able to attempt my solution (which does not rely on sp_rename) in production?

Comment: I tried your solution but it would didn't work either.  The object name I am trying to rename is actually 'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix'.  So that tell sp_rename to look in the dbo Schema for FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix.  Which does not exist.  The object name with schema is dbo.dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix.  The double dbo. is the problem.

Comment: I understand the problem.  I don't understand _"I tried your solution but it would didn't work either"_ because you don't explain why you are not able to drop the constraint in Production.  Does it error?  You don't have permissions?

Comment: Trying to rename a constraint 'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix' . sp_rename could not find the object. The problem is the Schema name got added to the actual constraint name. So the full object name with schema was 'dbo.dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix'.  For sp_rename you give the schema and object name that you are wanting to rename.  if I enter 'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix'.  It would look in schema 'dbo; for object 'FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix'.  if I entered 'dbo.dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix' sp_rename would error with to may parameters.

Comment: This is @Morpheus.  You are not looking at my answer.  My answer is a workaround for `sp_rename()`.  I recommended `ALTER TABLE <your-table-name> DROP CONSTRAINT dbo.dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix`.

Comment: I had read you comment and looked at your work around.  The question I had was why sp_rename could not find the object.  Which  was because the Schema Name got added to the Object Name.  Which is what I needed to fix on my production database that is described in my second post.  Yes there are several work around to the sp_rename.  But the work around wouldn't answer the question on why it had the problem.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "Need to fix this on my production database."  I only followed up with the suggested workaround in hopes of helping you solve the problem in production.  Then you responded "I tried your solution but it would didn't work either."

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_rename` with type:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_rename 
   'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix',
   'FK_FRPFileID_FRPDataMatrixImportETL',
   'OBJECT';
```

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
                    col1 INT NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE tab2 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)

ALTER TABLE tab1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix FOREIGN KEY (col1)
REFERENCES tab2(ID);

 EXEC dbo.sp_rename 
   'dbo.FK_FRP_File_DataMatrix',
   'FK_FRPFileID_FRPDataMatrixImportETL',
   'OBJECT';

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd272/2/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Drop the constraint on the **old** table (`Table1_Old`):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1_Old DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_Table2
GO
```

Add the constraint with the **new name** on the **old** table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1_Old  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_Table2_Old FOREIGN KEY(FileId)
REFERENCES dbo.Table2 (FileId)
GO
```

Now you are free to add the constraint on the **new** table (`Table1`) with the **old name** of `FK_Table1_Table2`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today. To add to the currently upvoted answer, you need to include brackets around each piece of the tablename like so:

```
sp_rename '[dbo].[table_column]', 'newvalue'
```